# HTML Generation from Xml File

Tags: c#, html, xml

I have a requirement to generate HTML page from Xml file, this Xml file will contain all input type control. There style sheets and java script validation methods. Can any one gives me any tool for this.
Thanks

Comment: You may like to use XMLReader to read elements (hint)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [xsl transformations](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) to generate html output from xml. These transformations can be applied at runtime by using [System.Xml.Xsl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70k6zz96.aspx) namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Use [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) should be able to solve this. You can try to use [oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) to do the transformations.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Jint](http://jint.codeplex.com/) for parsing and validation your javascript. For HTML parsing, I would suggest [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and for CSS styling, I would suggest [this CSS parser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/CSSParser.aspx).

All you need to do is read your XML file into an XMLDocument object, then you can run it against all 3 of these tools.